# Drupal 7 get a list of taxonomy terms in views

Tags: drupal, view

In Views (Drupal 7), how do I generate a list of terms from my taxonomy list called `tag`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's not clear from your question if you just want Views to display all the terms in the Tags vocabulary or if you are asking about generating a list of tags used to categorize content (for the latter, it would be a "Show content of type x" (i.e. "Node view").

If all you want is to show all the tags in your Tags vocabulary, you create a View to "Show Taxonomy terms of type Tag". You'll find options to create page or block displays. There are several "Display format" options:

- Grid
- HTML List
- Jump Menu
- Table
- Unformatted list

If you click on "Continue and edit", you'll find that, by default, the terms in the list are links. Clicking them takes you to a display of "teasers" for any content tagged with the term. You can adjust the sort order, add filtering, etc, and continue to tweak your displays.

Here is a screenshot of the initial step for creating a View of Taxonomy terms:
[image]